# What clang optimization flags should I apply to my OS X 10.5+ universal (i86/x64) binary?

Tags: macos, optimization, clang, cc

Currently, I am compiling:

```
clang -Oz -g
```

But I would like to apply an `-mtune` and if possible an `-march` flag, and anything else that will be valid on all Intel architectures that OS X Leopard supports.

***Specifically I am asking: which `-mtune` and `-march` flag should I specify so that my binary is optimized for 10.5, and will run on all supported Intel processors for 10.5?***

In addition, I would like to apply different tunings to the 32 bit and 64 bit portions, is this possible? If so what should I tune the 64 bit portion to?

For bonus points, I am interested in the same for PowerPC, for future reference, though currently I do not support that.

Answer (score 1):

You can build separate binaries using different `-march` and other flags, though be aware that `-march` can use instructions not available on earlier processors. `-mtune` and `-mcpu` can choose instructions, alignment, etc., that will *favour* a particular processor, yet run on all processors in that family.

To tune to different architectures (i386, x86-64, ppc, ppc64) you would have to consult the manual pages for clang / gcc. After separate builds it should be possible to use [lipo](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/lipo.1.html) to create a universal binary. There's a simple example [here](http://ngmarley.com/blog/osx-universal-binary/).

---

For Apple's compilers, you should use the `-arch` specification, and `-mmacosx-version-min=10.5`, provided you still have the SDKs for 10.5.